# When attempted to pass a test using next.js with jest I cannot seem to get the image import to mock correctly, why am I getting an error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, next.js, jestjs

When attempting to pass a test using Jest in Next.js I cannot seem to get the imported image to be mocked by Jest.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I followed the steps in the Next.js documentation.

My fileMock.js which is in `<rout>/__mocks__/fileMock.js`

```
export default {
  src: "/img.jpg",
  height: 24,
  width: 24,
  blurDataURL: "data:image/png;base64,imagedata",
};
```

And my jest.config.js has:

```
  export default {
  collectCoverage: true,
  // on node 14.x coverage provider v8 offers good speed and more or less good report
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    "**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "!**/*.d.ts",
    "!**/node_modules/**",
    "!<rootDir>/out/**",
    "!<rootDir>/.next/**",
    "!<rootDir>/*.config.js",
    "!<rootDir>/coverage/**",
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Handle CSS imports (with CSS modules)
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#mocking-css-modules
    "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",

    // Handle CSS imports (without CSS modules)
    "^.+\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js",

    // Handle image imports
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#handling-static-assets
    "^.+\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|avif|ico|bmp|svg)$/i":
      "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",

    // Handle module aliases
    "^@/components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/components/$1",
    "^@/pages/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/pages/$1",
  },
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  // setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/", "<rootDir>/.next/"],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  transform: {
    // Use babel-jest to transpile tests with the next/babel preset
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": ["babel-jest", { presets: ["next/babel"] }],
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/",
    "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$",
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"],
};
```

Is there any reason why doing these steps will still lead to an error.  This error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Applications/AMPPS/www/Vegan Food Blog/pages/public/assets/Branch1.svg:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                                                                                      ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

       5 | import Image from "next/image";
       6 | // import FLOWER_1_SVG from "./public/assets/Asset1.svg";
    >  7 | import BRANCH_1_SVG from "./public/assets/Branch1.svg";
         | ^
       8 | import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
       9 |
      10 | const title = "Home | The Vegan Blog";

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1496:14)
      at Object.require (pages/index.jsx:7:1)
      at Object.require (__tests__/index.test.js:7:1)
```

"type": "module" is enabled in the package.json too.

I'm not sure what is stopping the image from being mocked.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the bug.  Seems that the issue was an error with the way a regular expression had been written in this line `"^.+\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|avif|ico|bmp|svg)$/i"`.